# How do I transfer this question asked on Stack Overflow to the Math Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, migration

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113595/what-could-be-the-applications-of-chaos-theory-in-computer-science) a few days back, and I seem to getting low views and hence no response to that query.

I am pretty sure that asking this question on Math.SE would have been better. How can I migrate this question from Stack Overflow to the [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) site?

Comment: Why Maths, when we have a [Computer Science site](http://cs.stackexchange.com)? That said, I'm not so sure your question fits the Q&A format, you are asking for a list of things without presenting us with a concrete problem to solve. These questions tend to attract primarily opinion based answers, and usually get closed.

Comment: Oh! In that case I will edit the content and present it in some better way! Thanks!

Comment: Since your SO question doesn't have any answers, you could simply delete it and repost the better version on Computer Science or Maths.

Comment: That would be better ... though the question has been closed already!

Comment: Well, closed doesn't mean deleted. If you decide to repost it to another site, you should still delete the SO version.

Answer (score 11):

When you wish to request a question moved to another site all you need to do is flag for moderation attention and ask for the question to be migrated. However, you should keep in mind that:

- Migration for questions older than 60 days is not possible, even for moderators
- Moderators will generally avoid migrating questions that are perfectly on topic on the site they were originally asked
- Moderators will generally avoid migrating questions that are unclear, or otherwise don't fit [our general expectations for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Nevertheless, deleting your question and re-posting it on another site is a lot faster, and it doesn't involve asking someone else for help. You can't delete your own question if it has upvoted answers, but if it doesn't, just delete it and then post it to the more suitable site.

(all) That said, the specific question doesn't really fit our guidelines for constructive questions. We generally expect questions to be build around a practical problem, and yours is a somewhat vague request for a list of stuff. I'm afraid it runs afoul of our ["please don't ask questions where every answer is equally valid" guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). For more details on our constructive guidelines:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)